# Override Save Model in Django

Tags: python, django, opencv

I'd like to override the save button in the model to run my script. My script contains Tensorflow code. So, what I am trying to do is to get the uploaded image to run in my script then the result image will save in the media. My script contains total count value so I would like to save it in the model. Please help.

**Model.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Import packages
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import sys

# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append("..")

# Import utilites
from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

from api import object_counting_api
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render

class District_1_2018(models.Model):
barangay = models.CharField(max_length=255)
totalarea = models.CharField(max_length=10)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='result/2018/district1') 
totalcount = models.CharField(max_length=10)

def __str__(self):
    return self.barangay
```

**Forms.py**

```
class District_1_2018Form(forms.ModelForm): 
class Meta: 
    model = District_1_2018
    fields = ['barangay', 'totalarea', 'image', 'totalcount']
```

**My script**

```
  # Name of the directory containing the object detection module we're using
  MODEL_NAME = 'inference_graph'
  IMAGE_NAME = 'Burol.png'

  # Grab path to current working directory
  CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()

  # Path to frozen detection graph .pb file, which contains the model that is used
  # for object detection.
  PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,'frozen_inference_graph.pb')

  # Path to label map file
  PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,'training','labelmap.pbtxt')

  # Path to image
  PATH_TO_IMAGE = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,IMAGE_NAME)

  # Number of classes the object detector can identify
  NUM_CLASSES = 2

  # Load the label map.
  # Label maps map indices to category names, so that when our convolution
  # network predicts `5`, we know that this corresponds to `king`.
  # Here we use internal utility functions, but anything that returns a
  # dictionary mapping integers to appropriate string labels would be fine
  label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
  categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
  category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

  # Load the Tensorflow model into memory.
  detection_graph = tf.Graph()
  with detection_graph.as_default():
      od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
      with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
          serialized_graph = fid.read()
          od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
          tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

      sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)

  # Define input and output tensors (i.e. data) for the object detection classifier

  # Input tensor is the image
  image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

  # Output tensors are the detection boxes, scores, and classes
  # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected
  detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')

  # Each score represents level of confidence for each of the objects.
  # The score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
  detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
  detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')

  # Number of objects detected
  num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

  # Load image using OpenCV and
  # expand image dimensions to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
  # i.e. a single-column array, where each item in the column has the pixel RGB value
  image = cv2.imread(PATH_TO_IMAGE)
  image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

  # Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
  (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
      [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
      feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})

  # Draw the results of the detection (aka 'visulaize the results')

  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image,
      np.squeeze(boxes),
      np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
      np.squeeze(scores),
      category_index,
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=1,
      min_score_thresh=0.50)

  # All the results have been drawn on image. Now display the image.
  path = 'media/result/2018/district1'
  cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path , 'Burol.png'), image)
  from utils.visualization_utils import treecount

  value = treecount
```

This is what I tried.

```
class District_1_2018(models.Model):
barangay = models.CharField(max_length=255)
totalarea = models.CharField(max_length=10)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='result/2018/district1') 
totalcount = models.CharField(max_length=10)

def __str__(self):
    return self.barangay

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
# Name of the directory containing the object detection module we're using
MODEL_NAME = 'inference_graph'
IMAGE_NAME = self.image

# Grab path to current working directory
CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()

# Path to frozen detection graph .pb file, which contains the model that is used
# for object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,'frozen_inference_graph.pb')

# Path to label map file
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,'training','labelmap.pbtxt')

# Path to image
PATH_TO_IMAGE = IMAGE_NAME

# Number of classes the object detector can identify
NUM_CLASSES = 2

# Load the label map.
# Label maps map indices to category names, so that when our convolution
# network predicts `5`, we know that this corresponds to `king`.
# Here we use internal utility functions, but anything that returns a
# dictionary mapping integers to appropriate string labels would be fine
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

# Load the Tensorflow model into memory.
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

    sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)

# Define input and output tensors (i.e. data) for the object detection classifier

# Input tensor is the image
image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

# Output tensors are the detection boxes, scores, and classes
# Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected
detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')

# Each score represents level of confidence for each of the objects.
# The score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')

# Number of objects detected
num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

# Load image using OpenCV and
# expand image dimensions to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
# i.e. a single-column array, where each item in the column has the pixel RGB value
image = cv2.imread(PATH_TO_IMAGE)
image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

# Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
(boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
    [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
    feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})

# Draw the results of the detection (aka 'visulaize the results')

vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    image,
    np.squeeze(boxes),
    np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
    np.squeeze(scores),
    category_index,
    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
    line_thickness=1,
    min_score_thresh=0.50)

# All the results have been drawn on image. Now display the image.
path = 'media/result/2018/district1'
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path , 'Burol.png'), image)

from utils.visualization_utils import treecount
totalcount = treecount

    super(District_1_2018, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But I'm getting this error.

```
TypeError at /admin/tcqd/district_1_2018/add/
<built-in function imread> returned NULL without setting an error

C:\tensorflow4\models\research\object_detection\tcqdsite\tcqd\models.py in save
    109. image = cv2.imread(IMAGE_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding the `save` for the model, try using django `pre_save` signal for the same. It has number of benefits over the `save` being overridden, primary being it keeps your custom logic seperate from django's code itself.

It also offers you the flexibility to modify your business logic at some point later instead of convulating the inbuilt `save` method, not to forget that if your custom logic is big and complex it will make the `save` method unneccessarily complex as well.

[Django Pre Save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#pre-save)